# What determines the number of threads for a TaskFactory spawned jobs?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have the following code:

```
var factory = new TaskFactory();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var i1 = i;
    factory.StartNew(() => foo(i1));
}

static void foo(int i)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine($"foo{i} - on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
}
```

I can see it only does 4 threads at a time (based on observation).  My questions:

1. What determines the number of threads used at a time?
2. How can I retrieve this number?
3. How can I change this number?

P.S. My box has 4 cores.

P.P.S.  I needed to have a specific number of tasks (and no more) that are concurrently processed by the TPL and ended up with the following code:

```
private static int count = 0;   // keep track of how many concurrent tasks are running

private static void SemaphoreImplementation()
{
    var s = new Semaphore(20, 20);  // allow 20 tasks at a time

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var i1 = i;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {                        
                s.WaitOne();
                Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

                foo(i1);
            }
            finally
            {
                s.Release();
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref count);
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
}

static void foo(int i)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.WriteLine($"foo{i:00} - on thread " + 
            $"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId:00}. Executing concurently: {count}");
}
```

Comment: The number of CPU cores.

Comment: @Enigmativity the number of cores has no meaning for IO-bound workloads and the TPL is clueless about IO.

Comment: @Enigmativity So the default rule for TPL is to have a max thread count that is equal to the CPU count?

Comment: @AngryHacker - Yes, that's my understanding.

Comment: Why do not change `Semaphore` to `SemaphoreSlim` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you are using a `Task` in .NET, you are telling the TPL to schedule a piece of work (via `TaskScheduler`) to be executed on the `ThreadPool`. Note that the work will be scheduled at its earliest opportunity and however the scheduler sees fit. This means that the `TaskScheduler` will decide how many threads will be used to run `n` number of tasks and which task is executed on which thread.

The TPL is very well tuned and continues to adjust its algorithm as it executes your tasks. So, in most cases, it tries to minimize contention. What this means is if you are running 100 tasks and only have 4 cores (which you can get using `Environment.ProcessorCount`), it would not make sense to execute more than 4 threads at any given time, as otherwise it would need to do more context switching. Now there are times where you want to explicitly override this behaviour. Let's say in the case where you need to wait for **some sort of IO to finish, which is a whole different story**.

In summary, trust the TPL. But if you are adamant to spawn a thread per task (not always a good idea!), you can use:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => /* your piece of work */, 
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

This tells the *Default*`Taskscheduler` to explicitly spawn a new thread for that piece of work.

You can also use your own `Scheduler` and pass it in to the `TaskFactory`. You can find a whole bunch of `Schedulers` [`HERE`](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/04/9990342.aspx).

Note another alternative would be to use **`PLINQ`** which again by default analyses your query and decides whether parallelizing it would yield any benefit or not, again in the case of a blocking IO where you are certain starting multiple threads will result in a better execution you can force the parallelism by using **`WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)`** you then can use **WithDegreeOfParallelism**, to give hints on how many threads to use **but** remember there is **no guarantee** you would get that many threads, as [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383719%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says:

> Sets the degree of parallelism to use in a query. Degree of
>   parallelism is the **maximum number** of concurrently executing tasks that
>   will be used to process the query.

Finally, I **highly** recommend having a read of [`THIS`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Task_Parallelism) great series of articles on `Threading` and `TPL`.

Comment: The TPL has no idea what the workload does. It *cannot possibly* be well-tuned for IO. The idea that the TPL "will do the right thing" is repeated all over the web but false. This question is a great example: 4 threads it a throughput-limiting choice.

Comment: Hence why I said: "a whole different story"!

Comment: @usr Exactly my thoughts.  There is no way TPL knows anything about my workflow.  I ended up implementing it with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` plus a Semaphore.

Answer (score 5):

If you increase the number of tasks to for example 1000000 you will see a lot more threads spawned over time. The TPL tends to inject one every 500ms.

The TPL threadpool does not understand IO-bound workloads (sleep is IO). It's not a good idea to rely on the TPL for picking the right degree of parallelism in these cases. The TPL is completely clueless and injects more threads based on vague guesses about throughput. Also to avoid deadlocks.

Here, the TPL policy clearly is not useful because the more threads you add the more throughput you get. Each thread can process one item per second in this contrived case. The TPL has no idea about that. It makes no sense to limit the thread count to the number of cores.

> What determines the number of threads used at a time?

Barely documented TPL heuristics. They frequently go wrong. In particular they will spawn an *unlimited number of threads* over time in this case. Use task manager to see for yourself. Let this run for an hour and you'll have 1000s of threads.

> How can I retrieve this number? How can I change this number?

You can retrieve *some* of these numbers but that's not the right way to go. If you need a guaranteed DOP you can use `AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(...)` or a custom task scheduler. You also can manually start `LongRunning` tasks. Do not mess with process global settings.

Comment: What do you mean by DOP? With `AsParallel()` in the case of a blocking IO you still need to give it hint by using `WithDegreeOfParallelism` otherwise it thinks the work is CPU bound and allocates threads differently so again on a 4-core machine `PLINQ` may run only 4 tasks at the same time.

Comment: @MaYaN yes, you always need to specify a DegreeOfParallelism (=DOP) with IO involved no matter how you do it. That is a key point: No library can know the correct value. You need to find it empirically (or through human guessing).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `SemaphoreSlim` because it doesn't use Windows kernel (so it can be used in Linux C# microservices) and also has a property `SemaphoreSlim.CurrentCount` that tells how many remaining threads are left so you don't need the `Interlocked.Increment` or `Interlocked.Decrement`. I also removed `i1` because `i` is value type and it won't be changed by the call of `foo` method passing the `i` argument so it's no need to copy it into `i1` to ensure it never changes (if that was the reasoning for adding `i1`):

```
private static void SemaphoreImplementation()
{
    var maxThreadsCount = 20; // allow 20 tasks at a time
    var semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(maxTasksCount, maxTasksCount);
    var taskFactory = new TaskFactory();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        taskFactory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            try
            {                        
                await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
                var count = maxTasksCount-semaphoreSlim.CurrentCount; //SemaphoreSlim.CurrentCount tells how many threads are remaining
                await foo(i, count);
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphoreSlim.Release();
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
}

static async void foo(int i, int count)
{
    await Task.Wait(100);
    Console.WriteLine($"foo{i:00} - on thread " + 
            $"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId:00}. Executing concurently: {count}");
}
```